# How to crawl a website to get all the links in a website using Scrapy in python?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am beginner in python and using scrapy to crawl all the link recursively and wanted to map each link to text found in that link.

For this, I need to define my own spider class which can take arguments of the name and list of type of website to crawl and i want to build a dictionary of the link to text present in website, but i am lacking concept objects in python class. I tried some in below code to run the scrapy by creating objects but it is giving me error.

Please help me to make the objects of the class (which pass the arguments having the name of webpage/website to crawl) and form the dictionary of `{'URL':'all text found in that URL'}`

```
#rinku
import scrapy
# class LinkExtractor():
class MyntraSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Myntra"
    # allowed_domains = ["myntra.com"]
    # start_urls = [
    #     "http://www.myntra.com/",
    # ]
    # name = "Linker"

    # def __init__(allowed_domains = [], start_urls = []):          
       #  self.allowed_domains = allowed_domains
       #  self.start_urls = start_urls 

    def __init__(self, allowed_domains=None, start_urls=None):
        super().__init__()

        # self.name = name
        if allowed_domains is None:
            self.allowed_domains = []
        else:
            self.allowed_domains = allowed_domains

        if start_urls is None:
            self.start_urls = []
        else:
            self.start_urls = start_urls  

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = scrapy.Selector(response)
        # extract all links from page
        all_links = hxs.xpath('*//a/@href').extract()
        # iterate over links
        for link in all_links:
            yield scrapy.http.Request(url=link, callback=print_this_link)

    def print_this_link(self, link):
        print("Link --> {this_link}".format(this_link=link))


m1 = MyntraSpider(["myntra.com"], ["http://www.myntra.com/"])

# m1 = MyntraSpider("Linker",["myntra.com"], ["http://www.myntra.com/",])
```

Output i am getting with not link being printed

```
(venv) C:\Users\Carthaginian\Desktop\projectLink\crawler>scrapy crawl Myntra
2019-08-14 13:32:51 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.7.3 started (bot: crawler)
2019-08-14 13:32:51 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.4.1.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 19.7.0, Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019), cryptography 2.7, Platform Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
2019-08-14 13:32:51 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'crawler', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'crawler.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['crawler.spiders']}
2019-08-14 13:32:51 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 3109504fb87f6b47
2019-08-14 13:32:51 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-08-14 13:32:52 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-08-14 13:32:52 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-08-14 13:32:52 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-08-14 13:32:52 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-08-14 13:32:52 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-08-14 13:32:52 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-08-14 13:32:52 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-08-14 13:32:52 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.015957,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 14, 8, 2, 52, 585291),
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 14, 8, 2, 52, 569334)}
2019-08-14 13:32:52 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: I created m1 object and tried to pass arguments but it is giving error as `class MyntraSpider(scrapy.Spider, name, allowed_domains = [], start_urls = []):
NameError: name 'name' is not defined`

Comment: You define class in wrong way - class is not function. If you need run with variables then you have to create `def __init__(self, variables):`

Comment: in python we use `self`, not `this`. But outside class's methods you don't need `self.` to create variable.

Comment: is the `def __init__(self, variables):` need to define inside the class but where i pass the argument with object of a class

Comment: when you run `MyntraSpider(scrapy.Spider, "Myntra", ["myntra.com"], ...)` then Python executes `Scraper.__init__(MyntraSpider, "Myntra", ["myntra.com"], ...)`

Comment: when you `yield` data and run script with option `-o output.csv` then it automatically save data in file `output.csv` so you don't have to create dictionary or other structure and save it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run with arguments you have to use `__init__`

```
class MyntraSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    def __init__(self, name, allowed_domains=None, start_urls=None):
        super().__init__()

        self.name = name

        if allowed_domains is None:
            self.allowed_domains = []
        else:
            self.allowed_domains = allowed_domains

        if start_urls is None:
            self.start_urls = []
        else:
            self.start_urls = start_urls
```

When you will run (without `scrapy.Spider`)

```
m1 = MyntraSpider("Myntra", ["myntra.com"], ["http://www.myntra.com/"])
```

then Python will execute something like

```
MyntraSpider.__init__(m1, "Myntra", ["myntra.com"], ["http://www.myntra.com/"])
```

---

If you generated project to run crawler then you don't create instance but you run scrapy which use spider automatically and have to send data in command line using

```
scrapy crawl MyntraSpider -a nama=Myntra -a allowed_domains=myntra.com -a start_urls=http://www.myntra.com/
```

but it will send it as strings so you may have to convert them into lists - ie. using `split()` in `__init__`

---

**EDIT:** Working code after using

```
full_link = response.urljoin(link)
```

to convert relative url to absolute url

and adding `self.` in `callback=self.print_this_link`

There is no need to create `hxs = scrapy.Selector(response)` because `response.xpath` works too.

It is standalone script which works without creating project. It yield url and page's title which is saved in `output.csv`

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "MySpider"

    def __init__(self, allowed_domains=None, start_urls=None):
        super().__init__()

        # self.name = name
        if allowed_domains is None:
            self.allowed_domains = []
        else:
            self.allowed_domains = allowed_domains

        if start_urls is None:
            self.start_urls = []
        else:
            self.start_urls = start_urls  

    def parse(self, response):
        print('[parse] url:', response.url)

        # extract all links from page
        all_links = response.xpath('*//a/@href').extract()

        # iterate over links
        for link in all_links:
            print('[+] link:', link)
            #yield scrapy.http.Request(url="http://www.myntra.com" + link, callback=self.print_this_link)
            full_link = response.urljoin(link)
            yield scrapy.http.Request(url=full_link, callback=self.print_this_link)


    def print_this_link(self, response):
        print('[print_this_link] url:', response.url)
        title = response.xpath('//title/text()').get() # get() will replace extract() in the future
        yield {'url': response.url, 'title': title}


# --- run without creating project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',

    # save in file as CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', # 
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.crawl(MySpider, allowed_domains=["myntra.com"], start_urls=["http://www.myntra.com/"])
c.start()
```

Comment: I have updated the post above but not got any link to display on the webpage

Comment: But my program is not printing any link, surprisingly the crawler is working

Comment: add print() in other places to see which part is executed and what you have in variables. It may help you see where is problem

Comment: I run code and it show new errors. First: it need `self.` in `callback=self.print_this_link`. Second: urls are relative so they don't have `http://www.myntra.com/` at start so `Request()` has problem with them. You could use `print()` in `parser()` to see it. You may use `"http://www.myntra.com" + link` or there is some function `follow()` which should add `http://www.myntra.com/` to relative url.

Comment: I added code which get url and page's title and save in csv

Comment: Thanks it worked well as per my expection, I have one query can it is possible if i make a some web-interface using django which take input for the starting URL and it crawls all links at the backend and send the result to webinterface

Comment: yes you can do it. You can run spider in thread or use Celery to start it outside Django. Later you have to check from time to  time if there are result in file on in database.

Comment: i tried to get all the text of body using ```text = response.xpath('//body//text()').get()
        yield {'url': response.url, 'title': title, 'text': text}``` but it is not save any body text why

Comment: I was also trying to save the all body text for this i can remove the white spaces but the body text is not getting to write in CSV file

Comment: try `.getall()` - doc: [extract() and extract_first()](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#extract-and-extract-first)

Comment: I found that this scrapy is not working recursively to get all possible link associated or which can be reached out using the starting URL. Is it true? if it is then can it is able to do? or need some modification in code. Thanks for your patience

Comment: it should get all possible urls if they are exist on any visited page, are not created by JavaScript, and are not restricted by `allowed_domain`. You may try to read `sitemap.xml` - maybe it will have all url existing on this portal.

Comment: Hi furas, I want to know that how we can define a rule in our spider to crawl all possible links, example in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52255112/how-to-recursively-scrape-every-link-from-a-site-using-scrapy

Comment: like in this code `rules = [
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(
                canonicalize=True,
                unique=True
            ),
            follow=True,
            callback="parse"
        )
    ]`